# Practical uses of antimatter in the present

Tags: applied-physics, antimatter

I recently found out that a PET scan stands for a [positron emission tomography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positron_emission_tomography). Are there any other practical uses of antimatter in the present?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if the other antiparticles have been exploited, but positrons are used in metallurgical studies. [Positron annihilation spectroscopy](http://books.google.com/books?id=-uj80fqU8LEC&pg=PA1633) is one particular application.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this counts as "practical", but antiprotons are used in the Tevatron to increase the center-of-mass energy of collisions with protons.

In the LHC, however, the rest-mass is so much smaller than the Lorentz-boosted mass in the center-of-mass frame, that it basically isn't worth the hassle of using antiprotons.

This may just be a quirk of historical naming, but anti-neutrinos are typically much more common than neutrinos, since they are formed via beta-decay, which is happening all around us all the time.

Comment: Anit-neutrinos from reactors, neutrinos from the sun, and both from cosmic rays...