# Uses of antimatter in the present

Tags: antimatter, applied-physics

Since the [previous question by Jaime Soto](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2368/44126) is now nearly 12 years old, I wondered if there were any new practical Uses for Antimatter except PET and the treating of certain types of cancer. So, are there any?

Comment: google comes up with this 2009 https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn17113-making-antimatter-and-putting-it-to-use/  ,  nothing new comes up

Comment: https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/2010-12-09

Comment: If you have an answer please add it to the previous post.